# C4827 warning overriding ToString in C++/CX Metro class

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, c++-cli, interop, winrt-component

I have a C++/CX Windows Store component class and I'd like to implement a custom public ToString method that I can invoke from C#.  It compiles fine but I'm getting an odd warning from the compiler.  Here is code that reproduces the warning:

```
public ref class Foo sealed
{
public:
    String^ ToString()
    {
        return ref new String(L"This is from class Foo");
    }
};
```

When I compile the above class Visual Studio 2013 shows this warning:

> warning C4827: A public 'ToString' method with 0 parameters should be
>   marked as virtual and override (Foo.cpp)

However when I add 'virtual override' on the method signature I get syntax errors in the compiler.  How can I override Object.ToString() from a C++/CX class?

Comment: Ah, my bad, I'll fix the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `virtual` goes at the beginning, the `override` goes at the end. Also, you can get rid of the `ref new String`, the compiler can figure out that you want the string constant to be treated as a `String^`.

```
public ref class Foo sealed
{
public:
    virtual String^ ToString() override
    {
        return "This is from class Foo";
    }
};
```